# How to initialize tuple of vectors out of a variadic template pack and list of objects which use the same template types?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, stdvector, c++20, stdtuple

Below is a simplified description of what I intend to do and the code with which I'm approaching it.

I have a structure `TEmitter<Ts...>` where `Ts...` is a list of components stored in a `std::tuple` inside of `TEmitter`.

Lets say there are two emitters:

```
 e1<A, B, C>
 e2<A, B, C>
```

I'd like to create a class `EmitterMemory<Ts...>` which takes an `std::initializer_list<TEmitter<Ts...>>` in the constructor, takes the components of each `TEmitter` apart, and puts them in std::vectors which are stored in a tuple, like:

```
EmitterMemory<A, B, C> {e1, e2}

(has a) stl::tuple
        |-stl::vector<A> = [A(e1), A(e2)]
        |-stl::vector<B> = [B(e1), B(e2)]
        |-stl::vector<C> = [C(e1), C(e2)]
```

Now in the code below I think I've managed to declare the class `EmitterMemory` correctly, I just don't know how to initialize the `std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>` out of the constructor parameter `std::initializer_list<TEmitter<Ts...>>`.

I'd need somehow to iterate through the components declared in variadic template `Ts...`, and for each of them invoke `get<T>(TEmitter<Ts...>)` and put the result inside the `std::vector<T>`.

Something that I'm manually doing in the 4 last lines of the `main()` function.

I'd need some help how to approach this, so it's done automatically in the class constructor.
Can you tell me if it's feasible?

#### Code

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct ComponentBase{};

template<typename T>
concept is_a_component = std::is_base_of_v<ComponentBase, T>;
template<typename ...T>
concept is_many_components = (is_a_component<T> && ...);

namespace components {
    struct Position : ComponentBase {};
    struct Shoot : ComponentBase {};
    struct Active : ComponentBase {};
    struct Emission : ComponentBase {};
}

struct EmitterBase {};
template<typename T>
concept is_an_emitter = std::is_base_of_v<EmitterBase, T>;

template<is_many_components... Ts>
class TEmitter : EmitterBase {    
    using Components = std::tuple<Ts...>;
public:
    explicit TEmitter(int id) : id{id} {};
    int id{0};    
    Components components = std::make_tuple(Ts()...);
};

template<is_a_component T>
auto &get(is_an_emitter auto &emitter) {
    return std::get<T>(emitter.components);
}

struct EmitterMemoryBase {};

template<is_many_components... Ts>
class EmitterMemory : EmitterMemoryBase {
    using TupleOfVectors = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t AmountComponents = sizeof...(Ts);
    TupleOfVectors components;

    EmitterMemory(std::initializer_list<TEmitter<Ts...>> emitters)
        : components { std::make_tuple<>(std::vector<Ts>{}...) } 
        { };
};

template<typename ...Ts>
concept is_a_memory = std::is_base_of_v<EmitterMemoryBase, Ts...> ;

template<is_a_component T>
auto &get(is_a_memory auto &memory) {
    return std::get<std::vector<T>>(memory.components);
}

int main () {
    using namespace components;
    auto e1 = TEmitter<Position, Shoot, Active>{1};
    auto e2 = TEmitter<Position, Shoot, Active>{2};

    auto &e1_position_component = get<Position>(e1);
    auto &e2_position_component = get<Position>(e2);
    auto memory = EmitterMemory<Position, Shoot, Active>({e1, e2});        
    auto &position_vector = get<Position>(memory);
    position_vector.emplace_back(e1_position_component);
    position_vector.emplace_back(e2_position_component);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly as you asked... with a variadic list of elements instead of an initializer list... but adding an helper method, should works as follows

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ems>
static std::vector<T> getVect(Ems const & ... ems)
 { return { get<T>(ems)... }; }

template <typename ... Ems>
EmitterMemory (Ems const & ... ems)
    : components { getVect<Ts>(ems...)... } 
    { }
```

Obviously you have to initialize `memory`

```
auto memory = EmitterMemory<Position, Shoot, Active>(e1, e2);
```

without brackets.

If you really want to use a `std::initializer_list` (but why?) you can send it to `getVect()` and unpack it inside the body of the method with a classic range-for.

**Unrequested Bonus**

Using the variadic constructor, you can add an explicit deduction guide

```
template <typename ... Es, typename ... Ts>
EmitterMemory (TEmitter<Es...>, Ts...) -> EmitterMemory<Es...>;
```

so you can initialize `memory` simply as follows

```
auto memory = EmitterMemory(e1, e2);
```

because the `is_main_components... Ts` template parameters (`Position, Shoot, Active`, in this case) are deduced from the first argument (`e1`).

Obviously this works if you initialize `memory` with at least an argument.

Comment: Thank you! I don't really need the std::initalizer_list, just didn't know how to formulate the helper function for populating the tuple of vectors, and yours works exactly like I needed.

Comment: @PatrykSzczypień - I've added an "unrequested bonus". Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip - I wasn't aware that you can do that but it's actually very helpful to let the compiler deduce the provided types instead of writing them each time.
So this deduction guide you can only write afterwards when a templated class has been already declared, yes? I mean you won't be able to provide it during declaration of a class because it uses two variadic packs, but afterwards is fine?

Comment: @PatrykSzczypień - The rules for [CTAD (Class Template Argument Deduction)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) are very complex. Take in count that declaring a class, your constructors add implicit deduction guides, but in this case there is no match between template arguments of the constructor and template arguments of the class; the example I've written is an explicit deduction guide that you can add when the implicit deduction guides aren't enough.